# asp.net mvc ajax request is not working on iis

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, url, url-rewriting

i am working on asp.net mvc with angularjs and it is working fine on localhost but publish angular request is not working and it is showing 404.

**Actual Code**

```
this.UserLogin = function (User) {
            var response = $http({
                method: "post",
                url:"/Login/Authorize",
                data: JSON.stringify(User),
                dataType: "json"
            });
            return response;
}
```

Below is working on IIS but not working on my local

```
rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")'

this.UserLogin = function (User) {
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: rootUrl + "/Login/Authorize",
            data: JSON.stringify(User),
            dataType: "json"
        });
        return response;
    }
```

I tried below but it is also not working please check screenshot [image: Error]

```
 this.UserLogin = function (User) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: '@Url.Action("Login","Authorize")',
        data: JSON.stringify(User),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
}
```

How we can set url so that its work fine on both local and iis.

Comment: use `@Url.Action` to generate the entire url. like `@Url.Action("Controllername","Actioname")`. It will work for both.

Comment: @GaganDeep please check my question @Url.Action("Controllername","Actioname") is not working,i have edit my question

Comment: what is the error you are getting on local??

Comment: are you on your cshtml page??? it seems the script is in the external js file

Comment: @GaganDeep no i am on external js file

Comment: in external file you cannot access `@Url`. you have to provide relative URL manually.

Comment: might be that in url production server  you have deplayed the website inside a subdirectory of the default website.

Comment: try removing the `~` from the url . start from the `/`

Comment: @GaganDeep,after removing ~ from
rootUrl = '@Url.Content("/")' then i am getting below error on local
 http://login/Authorize 404

Comment: you will not be able to use @Url . use relative URL